# div style attribute does not work

Tags: javascript, html

i would like to hide a div by default onload.

this should be easy, and i'm frustrated why it is not working. what i did is this:

```
<div id="DivToHide" style="display: none;">
  <tr>
     <td>
        //calling some JSP taglibs that gets from a Java class controller
        <td width="169"><%= stockData %> </td>
     </td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

The div kept showing up in IE and Chrome. What's wrong?

Comment: it works when I place it in a fiddle..is there somewhere else in your code that might be affecting this?

Comment: Your code is fine. Somewhere else in your codebase is overwriting/changing what you have there.

Comment: any javascript / jquery that sets the style on that div?

Comment: try using `style="display: none !important;"`

Comment: may be possible that you use same id somewhere else on your file.

Comment: @JayPatel so if there is another element with same id? i'd like to hear more about another element with same id overriding inline style.. ~

Comment: You can't nest tr inside div.  Had you tried to do it right?  (put a table inside div, and the tr inside the table)?

Comment: conflict some time when you use same id multiple time. we can use class more than 1 time but not id.so that might create problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, wrong nesting.  See example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <script>

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style='display:none'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> You will not see this.? </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <table>
            <div style='display:none'>
                <tr>
                    <td> Wrong nesting.  some browsers might show it, some others will hide it. </td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```